# Cannot get parallel processing to work in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

This code is always throwing the error "[Errno 32] Broken pipe" (the error is thrown on the line that says processes[i].start()):

```
from NetworkEnsemble import NetworkEnsemble
from multiprocessing import Process

NUM_NETWORKS = 2

def train_network(ensemble, network_num):
    ensemble.train_network(network_num)

ensemble = NetworkEnsemble( NUM_NETWORKS, (600), 0.01)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("[BEGIN TRAINING]")
    processes = list()
    for i in range(NUM_NETWORKS):
        processes.append(Process(target=train_network, args=(ensemble, i, )))
        processes[i].start()

    for i in range(NUM_NETWORKS):
        processes[i].join()
    print("[END TRAINING]")

ensemble.full_ensemble_evaluation()
```

why is this approach not working?

Comment: Are you running on Windows? If so, `ensemble = NetworkEnsemble( NUM_NETWORKS, (600), 0.01)` and `ensemble.full_ensemble_evaluation()` are being called in the child processes. Is there some reason why it would break?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is actually on the prior line

```
  processes.append(Process(target=train_network, args=(ensemble, i, )))
```

should be:

```
  processes.append(Process(target=train_network, args=(ensemble, i )))
```

the extra comma at the end of your list of arguments causes the argument list to keep looking for another entry instead of closing.  This causes a syntax error on the next line because the parser is still trying to find another argument for the prior line.

Comment: No, its okay to have trailing commas in python list, tuple and dicts. For instance `(1,2,)` is just `(1,2)`.

Comment: list and tuple, yes.  Argument list?  I think it is trying to pass a non-existent third parameter to `train_network` causing the `broken pipe` message.

Comment: If you focus on just the parameter expression `args=(ensemble, i, )` its just a `tuple` that will be sent to the process and and expanded as the positional arguments to `train_network`. OP would have gotten a syntax error if this was the problem. But a broken pipe (which means the subprocess started) is seen instead.